# How to input tuple to caffe layer?

Tags: caffe, pycaffe, lmdb

I'm totally new in caffe and I'm try to convert a tensorflow model to caffe.
I have a tuple which's shape is a little complex for it's stored some word vector.
This is the shape of the tuple data——

```
data[0]: a list, [684, 84], stores the sentence vector;
data[1]: a list, [684, 84], stores the position vector;
data[2]: a matrix, [684, 10], stores the aspects of the sentence;
data[3]: a matrix, [1, 684], stores the label of each sentence;
data[4]: a number, stores the max length of sentences;
```

Each row represents a sentences, which is also a sample of the dataset.

In tf, I return the whole tuple from a function which is wrote by myself.

```
train_data = read_data(FLAGS.train_data, source_count, source_word2idx)
```

I noticed that caffe always requires a data layer before training the data, but I don't have ideas how to convert my data to lmdb type or just sent them as a tuple or matrix into the model.

By the way, I'm using pycaffe.

Counld anyone help?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no particular magic; all you need to do is to write an input routine that reads the file and returns the data in the format expected for `train_data`.  You do not need to pre-convert your data to LMDB or any other format; just write `read` data to accept your current input format, and give the model the format it requires.

We can't help you from there: you haven't specified the model's format at all, and you've given us only the shape for the input data (no internal structure or semantics).  Simply treat the data as if you were figuring out how to organize the input data for a given output format.